# If I have a directory of JPEG's, how can I create one long stitched image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpg

I exported a Flash video (.flv) to jpeg sequence. All 450 frames are in a folder, and now I'd like to stitch them all together so the result is one super long image.

For example, instead of 450 images, each 320x240px, I want one image which is 144000x240px.

Is there a Photoshop option to do this or another software tool I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File >> scripts >> Load files into stack

Browse for your 450 images, select them all, and press open. This will take a long time!

When it's finished the process go to: image >> canvas size

Change the width of the document to your desired amount.

Now align the first frame to the far left of the canvas, and the last frame to the far right.

Select all layers and select "distribute horizontal centers"

Comment: Ack, I was hoping for an automated solution, even if it's not Photoshop. The closest I got was File->Automate->PhotoMerge. Is there not a way to batch load image files onto the canvas?

Comment: that's a pretty quick solution, all things considered!

Comment: Oh, I was mistaken - I tried it and I can totally select all the files at once. I thought you meant I had to open all 450 files individually. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question - I can only save as `.psb`, `.raw`, or `.tiff`. Trick to save as jpeg?

Comment: When an image becomes too large you lose certain formats. What is the intended use for this image?

Comment: Just to follow up, the intended use was to apply it as a background image to a div, and have javascript slide it over incrementally at a set frame rate, emulating a movie film strip. JPEG seemed to cap out at like 65000px wide/high. Thanks again.

Comment: It might still be better to use multiple images (maybe an image per frame) and run through those. You can still line them up horizontally. Plus if it's all one image the whole thing needs to load which could take a while. A lot of smaller files is better.